# Force timeout settings in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I have configured the timeout settings as below in my web.config.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Since I'm using a shared hosting environment, I can not change the IIS settings for timeout.
Currently it seems that this timeout is not working and it occurs after 15-20 mins of idle time.

are there any settings to force the timeout to take the value in web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly adding the machine key to the web.config solved the issue.

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey